# is there any free mvc5 hosting available along with sql server 2012?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, web-hosting, asp.net-mvc-5.1

i have searched for a lot of free websites but either they don't provide MVC5 hosting for free or they demand money for it.

i wanted to deploy MVC5 site to show client, is there any free MVC5 hosting available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Azure Web Sites](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/) has a free tier including 1GB of storage and a 20MB SQL Server database. You can even deploy in one click from Visual Studio.

Comment: they provide one month trial only?

Comment: The free tier of Web Sites is always free, and allows up to 10 active sites. Trial offers vary; whatever the Azure site tells you is the current trial offer in your location.

Comment: @HasanAliKaraca It requires a credit card so you can easily upgrade your plan later. The free tier is free.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found [HostBuddy.com](http://www.hostbuddy.com/). They have a 2-month free hosting plan. They don't require any credit card and their [free features](http://www.hostbuddy.com/hosting_plans) are sufficient.

I struggled to find a free (no credit card) .NET hosting for long time, so I can imagine it can help someone in the future.